# Has-many relationship in classes

Tags: python, dictionary, has-many

I'm trying to get an idea of has-many relationship in python classes, although theoretically I understood the concept but when I try to implement it, I'm not getting correct output:

Code:

```
## Animal is-a object
class Animal(object):
    def sound(str):
        print("sound of animals")
## Dog is-a Animal, Dag has a name
class Dog(Animal):
    """docstring for Dog."""
    def __init__(self, name):
        #super(Dog, self).__init__()
        #initializing dog name
        self.name = name
    def sound(str):
        print("Dog barks")

## Cat is-a animal, Cat also has a name
class Cat(Animal):
    """docstring for Cat."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        # initializing cat name
        self.name  = name
    def sound(str):
        print("Cat meows")

    ## Person has-a pet of some kind
## Person is-a object
class Person(object):
    """docstring for Person."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        #super(Person, self).__init__()
        self.name  = name
        ## Person has-a pet of some kind
        self.pet = None
## rover is-a dog
rover = Dog("Rover")
rover.sound()
## Satan is-a cat
satan = Cat("Satan")
tiger = Cat("tiger")
satan.sound()
## Mary is-a Person
Mary = Person("Mary")
Mary.pets = [satan ,tiger , rover ] # list of pets
Mary.pets ={'cats' : [satan, tiger] , 'dogs': [rover]} #dictionary of lists of pets
print("No. of pets mary has ")
for x,y in Mary.pets.items(): 
    print(x, ":" , y)
```

Is this correct syntax for getting all dictionary values from a  object:

```
for x,y in Mary.pets.items(): 
    print(x, ":" , y)
```

I'm getting this output:

```
Dog barks
Cat meows
No of pets mary has
cats : [<__main__.Cat object at 0x011F0D30>, <__main__.Cat object at 0x011F0CF0>]
dogs : [<__main__.Dog object at 0x011F0CD0>]
```

Why am i getting address rather than value?

Comment: You want to implement `__repr__` for your classes. See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: @MaxGasner  : so what changes should i make ?

Comment: That is simply the standard `__repr__` inherited from `object`. What else did you expect, what would be 'the value'? you have a bunch of objects in a `list`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : got your point instead of objects if i provide key , pair( where pair may be a list ) it is working fine as expected .Also a new thing for me to learn today```_repr_```   :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. everything is an object in python anyway. I was really just asking *what you were expecting*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga :  I was expecting list instead of object address (also without braces )

Comment: `[<__main__.Cat object at 0x011F0D30>, <__main__.Cat object at 0x011F0CF0>]` is a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : i'm new to this ,still figuring out , i know it's a list but it would be better if i can get values i mean like i like satan, rover , tiger (as in my code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below

The name property is kept on the base class. The base class implements **repr** as well

```
## Animal is-a object
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def sound(str):
        print("sound of animals")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

## Dog is-a Animal, Dag has a name
class Dog(Animal):
    """docstring for Dog."""
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)

    def sound(str):
        print("Dog barks")

## Cat is-a animal, Cat also has a name
class Cat(Animal):
    """docstring for Cat."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)

    def sound(str):
        print("Cat meows")

    ## Person has-a pet of some kind
## Person is-a object
class Person(object):
    """docstring for Person."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        #super(Person, self).__init__()
        self.name  = name
        ## Person has-a pet of some kind
        self.pet = None
## rover is-a dog
rover = Dog("Rover")
rover.sound()
## Satan is-a cat
satan = Cat("Satan")
tiger = Cat("tiger")
satan.sound()
## Mary is-a Person
Mary = Person("Mary")
Mary.pets = [satan ,tiger , rover ] # list of pets
Mary.pets ={'cats' : [satan, tiger] , 'dogs': [rover]} #dictionary of lists of pets
print("No. of pets mary has ")
for x,y in Mary.pets.items():
    print(x, ":" , y)
```

output

```
Dog barks
Cat meows
No. of pets mary has 
('cats', ':', [Satan, tiger])
('dogs', ':', [Rover])
```

Comment: Can we remove these braces ?
```
('cats', ':', Satan, tiger)
('dogs', ':', Rover)
```

Comment: @LuciFiEr try to do it your self as an exercise. If you fail you can ask again.

Comment: one way  i thought about doing it is to convert dictionary to string and replace [ ] with spaces , is there any efficient way of doing this?